# Global static const string variables in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

(Newbie alert)

I'm having trouble initializing a constant static string in objective-C:

Basically what I want to do is create a constant string from a `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(...)`

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your definition of a constant string? Do you mean a `const char*`, an `@"String" or a non-mutable `NSString` ?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a static string in one of your implementation files. In either the class's `initialize` method or another appropriate setup point (depending on the exact circumstances — the `sharedInstance` method would be a good place in a singleton, for example), assign the localized string to the variable.